# AppStore payout exchange rate

Tags: ios, app-store

Does anyone have experience with Appstore payout in other currency than USD?

When my bank account is in CZK currency and I set it in iTunes Connect, I will receive all money from Apple in CZK. But what is the real exchange rate? Do they use standard mid-market exchange rate or do I lose some money on the conversion?

And what about Google Play, do you have experience with this too?

I'm sorry if this question is off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Yeah, I was not sure about that .. but in help there is stated that question can be "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" which I think it is, because often it is the developer (me) who cares about the payment and other developers could know this :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke to a person who does receive money from AppStore and he showed me his payout info. It is really mid-market exchange rate.